# Local Notification pop-up is displayed after killing the application

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I have implemented Local notification in my application, I had a issue in below scenario:

Scenario:App is launched, Location notification will be created to display after a week from current date in login screen,I have logged in with credentials and after logging in double tap on the device's Home button (bottom center phisical key) to bring up the recently used applications bar then tap and hold on the application icon in order to be able to kill the application.After killing the application the notification pop-up is presented without waiting for a week time

Below is the code:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (iPhoneClientConfig::getInstance()->getReminder() == RS_NONE) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
    else {
        int daysToAdd;
        NSString *alertText;
        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        if (iPhoneClientConfig::getInstance()->getReminder() == RS_MONTH) {
            daysToAdd = 60*60*24*30;
            alertText = [Localization getLanguage:@"reminder_message_month"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSMonthCalendarUnit;
            [self generateAlertNotifications:daysToAdd withtext:alertText ];
        } else if (iPhoneClientConfig::getInstance()->getReminder() == RS_DAY) {
            daysToAdd = 60*60*24;
            alertText = [Localization getLanguage:@"reminder_message_day"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
        } else if (iPhoneClientConfig::getInstance()->getReminder() == RS_HOUR) {
            daysToAdd = 60*60;
            alertText = [Localization getLanguage:@"reminder_message_hour"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSHourCalendarUnit;
        } else {
            if (iPhoneClientConfig::getInstance()->getReminder() != RS_WEEK) {
                LOG.error("%s: Unexpetected reminder repeat interval in configuration, fall back to week",__FUNCTION__);
            }
            daysToAdd = 60*60*24*7;
            alertText = [Localization getLanguage:@"reminder_message_week"];
            localNotification.repeatInterval =  NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            [self generateAlertNotifications:daysToAdd withtext:alertText];
        }

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *newDate = [today addTimeInterval:daysToAdd];
         NSLog(@"newDate:%@",newDate);
        // Set up the fire time
        localNotification.fireDate = newDate;
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        // Notification details and Set the action button
        localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
        localNotification.alertAction = [Localization getLanguage:@"local_notif_alert"];
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        //Schedule LocalNotification
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
        NSLog(@"local_notif_alert:%@",localNotification);
        [localNotification release];
    }
}
```

I have the fire date & local notification in console as below:

```
Date:2012-09-01 10:49:08 +0000

local_notif_alert:<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0xd006d20>{fire date = Saturday, September 1, 2012 4:19:08 PM India Standard Time, time zone = Asia/Kolkata (IST) offset 19800, repeat interval = NSWeekCalendarUnit, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Saturday, September 1, 2012 4:19:08 PM India Standard Time}
```

Comment: can you please post some code how you generate the notification?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Once they are scheduled, local notifications have a life of their own.
This is what you have to do: call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

for example in `applicationWillTerminate:`.

As for the unexpected notification appearing too early: `NSLog` the notification details and make sure you got the scheduling right.

Comment: I have called cancelAllNotifications and then scheduled the new notification as in the above code, even though I am able to get notification when I am killing the app.

Comment: Please delete your app, clean your project, restart your phone/simulator, and try again. Some notifications maybe stuck if you perhaps changed the bundleID or something.